# AWS IOT list things with more than one attributes

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, iot

In AWS IOT Core,

I would like to list things and filter with more than one attributes. For example I want to filter with 3 attributes at the same time

Is it possible?

```
  // List all iotThings based on search criteria in listThingsRequest
  export const listThings = async (listThingsRequest: ListThingsRequest) => {
    return iot.listThings(listThingsRequest).promise()
  }
```

But in the ListThingsRequest it just take one attributeName & attributeValue only as below. How to pass multiple attributes and values ?

```
export interface ListThingsRequest {
    /**
     * To retrieve the next set of results, the nextToken value from a previous response; otherwise null to receive the first set of results.
     */
    nextToken?: NextToken;
    /**
     * The maximum number of results to return in this operation.
     */
    maxResults?: RegistryMaxResults;
    /**
     * The attribute name used to search for things.
     */
    attributeName?: AttributeName;
    /**
     * The attribute value used to search for things.
     */
    attributeValue?: AttributeValue;
    /**
     * The name of the thing type used to search for things.
     */
    thingTypeName?: ThingTypeName;
    /**
     * When true, the action returns the thing resources with attribute values that start with the attributeValue provided. When false, or not present, the action returns only the thing resources with attribute values that match the entire attributeValue provided. 
     */
    usePrefixAttributeValue?: usePrefixAttributeValue;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not native supported by AWS, as the official [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/list-things.html) states that only an "attribute-name" and an "attribute-value" are allowed to be specified.

However, we can filter by the most restrictive attribute (which returns less results), and then programmatically iterate over results to further filter the result set before returning it.

If this is not a valid option, as the API returns lots of items, the only solution here is to add an attribute that matches the expected filter. For instance the concatenation of the three values.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine in CLI commands when i tried with 2 attributes. But not sure about Javascript SDKs.   CLI command i tried was like this. aws iot list-things --attribute-name state --attribute-value s1 --attribute-name model --attribute-value m1

Comment: ¿It is working or it is just using the second attribute "model"? As far as I know it is only possible to specify one attribute. So, using the option "--attribute-name" multiple times overrides the previous ones.